# Generar numeros alfanumericos en MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

tengo una aplicación en mvc 5 asp.net y me gustaría generar unos numero alfanuméricos automáticamente ejemplo de resultado que quiero: B0100002062 y que se vayan incrementando a medida que vaya insertando registros, agradecería el aporte

Comment: Que tipo de aporte esperas? que probaste? que hiciste hasta ahora? de donde salen esos numeros? como se forman? Por favor mira [ask]

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que te deje. Saludos.

Comment: lo que sucede es lo siguiente quiero que automáticamente inserte un registro apatir de esa numeración me siga incrementando, ejemplo B0100002062, B0100002063, así sucesivamente, me doy a entender

Answer (score -1):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un GUID, este es un identificador unico que contiene una cadena alfanumerica aleatoria.

Para ello utiliza lo siguiente

```
using System.Guid

var x = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

esto debería crearte un guid como este `285f320f-892f-4e09-9d25-14c717e0dfd2`

Puedes revisar el mismo ejemplo haciendo clic [aca](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QQ1pUW) ò para saber mas acerca de esto, visita la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) Espero que te allá logrado ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: lo que quiero es que B0100002062 se me incremente a medida que valle insertando un registro, ejemplo B0100002062, B010000206, ect

Comment: Con que fin quieres lograr eso? por que para ello existe el campo id en la table de tu db donde lo puedes colocar auto incrementable.

Comment: con el fin de que con 1 o dos caracteres me incremente el valor como si fuera una secuencia